# cck imagefield upload problem?

Tags: php, drupal-6, cck

I have a cck field of type "file". I used this for uploading of images. On my local server running on apache, uploading of image using the field is fine. But on the deployed version or the web server, the upload won't work. On the web server, I can select an image and when I hit upload, it will then display the image but when I click on save the image is gone.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Best regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the permissions of the sites/default/files directory of your Drupal site (or the directory you've set for file uploads if you changed it). If it's not writeable, Drupal won't be able to save your file on the server.